# How do I get the text box value from React onchange 'CurrentTarget' is null

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I have a SPFX webpart that uses the React Framework.  I'm trying to set the state based on a textfield onChange.  All of the examples I've seen do it based on the event value or the React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement CurrentTarget value.  I believe the old way was using the event value because that is not available/been replaced with the React.FormEvent.  Anyway, here's what I'm trying to do.  However, the CurrentTarget is null when I debug:

[image]

Comment: Where is the `<TextField>` coming from?  Some type of existing library?  If so, have you checked the docs for how the `onChange` parameter works?  It is quite possible that they do events in their own way.